# Create a Forms Authentication site

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, forms-authentication, umbraco

My site works great with the backend Umbraco stuff for a user to log in and change the content etc. What i am looking to do is create a login reg section for the front facing site so users can leave comments etc.
I have created my login reg page and tried using .NET Forms Authentication but nothing seems to work! When I add the cookie, I refresh and it's not there. This method works great in non Umbraco sites, so I am assuming that I need to do something different with Umbraco.

Here is my Forms Authentication code, which doesn't seem to add cookies or SetAuthCookie:

```
Users Users = new Users();
        ENT_User User = Users.GetUser(this.txtLogin.Text, this.txtLoginPassword.Text);

        if (User.ID != Guid.Empty)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
              User.Email,
              DateTime.Now,
              DateTime.Now.AddDays(12),
              true,
              User.ID.ToString(),
              FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

            // Encrypt the ticket.
            string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

            // Create the cookie.
            Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("LoginDetails", encTicket));
```

}

When I hover my mouse over the cookies in Debug the cookie is there, but when I refresh and come through the process again, the Cookie is not there.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: If you have tried my suggestion for a fix, please confirm if it helped or not. If it does not work as intended, we may look for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You've set expiration for the ticket, but not for the cookie itself.
Try to change:

```
...
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("LoginDetails", encTicket));
```

to:

```
...
var httpCookie = new HttpCookie("LoginDetails", encTicket);
httpCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(12);
Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);
```

Comment: Do you use ASP.NET Web Development Server to run your web application (server used by Visual Studio by default, I suppose)? If so, try to deploy the application on your local IIS if possible and test if the issue still occurs in that case.

Comment: It may sound odd, but make sure name of your application and its path does NOT contain any underscore characters. I think this can cause some issues with cookies.